# Text Marquee in WPF only

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have this code, is for move a text Marquee as you can see in the newscasts. It working in *Windows.Forms*, but not in *WPF*.

```
this.Refresh();
myLabel2.Left += 5;
if (myLabel2.Left >= this.Width) {
    myLabel2.Left = myLabel2.Width * -1;
}
```

The above *Windows.Forms* code will move the label containing the Marquee text from right to left until it gets to the edge and then reset to the the right.

I want to replicate the same effect in *WPF* but don't know where to start.

Comment: Improved some grammar and formatted the code block. Not sure what you mean with *fresh news*.

Comment: I need a TextBlock move from left to right, as the bottom strip of a newscast. When the TextBlock move to the right and disappear, appear on the left side again. The above code works as I want, but in Windows Form. I want the same thing in WPF. And sorry, but I do not speak much English

Comment: @ArneClaassen Editing to tidy up and make things clearer is good, but italicising things when they don't need to be doesn't add value.

Comment: Animation is a built in feature in WPF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @slugster appreciate the feedback.  Got over eager with formatting

Comment: Thanks Arne and slugster, and I appreciate your comments. Yes, I'm new in this Forum and I have a problem with my project. If you have any idea for my problem, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

These links will be useful to you -

- http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2008/08/silverlight-marquee-control.html
- http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2008/08/wpf-custom-controls-marquee-control.html

They contain detailed information on implementing the marquee behavior using WPF controls.